# Kafka connect to azure data lake connector task failed

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, azure-data-lake-gen2

I'm using InstaClustr managed service where Kafka bootstrap server and Kafka connect reside. I have uploaded a connector I downloaded from:
https://docs.axual.io/connector-catalog/current/adls-gen2-sink/index.html

After I started the connector, I got an error message indicated below:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GZaJC.png)

It says 'Null scanresults or scanresults types are not supported', however, I have no clue what does it entail, and I'm very new to Java.

My configuration is like this:

```
**{
  "name": "my-connector",
  "config": {
    "connector.class": "io.axual.connect.plugins.adls.gen2.AdlsGen2SinkConnector",
    "tasks.max": "3",
    "topics": "test",
    "adls.endpoint": "https://accountname.dfs.core.windows.net",
    "adls.container.name": "test",
    "adls.auth.method": "AccountKey",
    "adls.account.name": "myexampleadlsaccount",
    "adls.account.key": "get-this-from-the-azure-storage-account-settings",
    "base.directory": "base"
  }
}**
```

,

The base directory was created in the azure data lake, however, after I put some messages through the console producer, nothing was generated in the data lake.

The error message is shown here:

```
{"state":"FAILED","trace":"org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Exiting WorkerSinkTask due to unrecoverable exception.
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.deliverMessages(WorkerSinkTask.java:609)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.poll(WorkerSinkTask.java:329)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.iteration(WorkerSinkTask.java:232)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.execute(WorkerSinkTask.java:201)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:186)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:241)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: io.axual.connect.plugins.adls.gen2.exceptions.AdlsGen2Exception: io.axual.connect.plugins.adls.gen2.exceptions.AdlsGen2Exception: Null scanresults or scanresult types are not supported
    at io.axual.connect.plugins.adls.gen2.AdlsGen2SinkTask.put(AdlsGen2SinkTask.java:157)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.deliverMessages(WorkerSinkTask.java:581)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: io.axual.connect.plugins.adls.gen2.exceptions.AdlsGen2Exception: Null scanresults or scanresult types are not supported
    at io.axual.connect.plugins.adls.gen2.avro.ContainerGenerator.determineInnerSchema(ContainerGenerator.java:118)
    at io.axual.connect.plugins.adls.gen2.avro.ContainerGenerator.createKafkaKeyValueContainer(ContainerGenerator.java:105)
    at io.axual.connect.plugins.adls.gen2.avro.ContainerGenerator.createContainer(ContainerGenerator.java:97)
    at io.axual.connect.plugins.adls.gen2.avro.AvroADLSFile.processRecords(AvroADLSFile.java:193)
    at io.axual.connect.plugins.adls.gen2.AdlsGen2SinkTask.lambda$put$4(AdlsGen2SinkTask.java:142)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195)
    at java.base/java.util.HashMap$EntrySpliterator.forEachRemaining(HashMap.java:1764)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:913)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.reduce(ReferencePipeline.java:558)
    at io.axual.connect.plugins.adls.gen2.AdlsGen2SinkTask.put(AdlsGen2SinkTask.java:143)\
    ... 11 more\","worker_id":"10.201.0.1:8083","generation":85}
```

Comment: Hi Arron, welcome to stack-overflow.
Can you provide a stack trace or the error from the log

Comment: Hi Haim, I have attached the error message above.